# How to use case expression for the below query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

I have this data with the following information:

```
AcctNumber  VisitID   TxnType   TxnJournal  TxnSvcDate  TxnBchDate  TxnNonChgCode  TxnAmount  TxnCount  TxnInsurance  ChgTotal
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 csc       V123456789  PAY       CASUCL     2/8/2019    2/8/2019    CHECK         -181.22          1            SP     3386.6
 csc       V123456789  PAY       CASUCL     2/9/2019    2/9/2019    CHECK         -175.48          1            SP     3386.6
 csc       V123456789  PAY       CASUCL     2/8/2019    2/8/2019    CHECK         -68.06           1            SP     3386.6
```

But I need the results to be as below, Where you can see all the columns are same except charges total in the below result, i want these charges to populate only once for same `VisitID` OR `AccountNumber` and remaining to be populated as Zero , Let me know how can we solve this through the query.

```
AcctNumber  VisitID   TxnType   TxnJournal  TxnSvcDate  TxnBchDate  TxnNonChgCode  TxnAmount  TxnCount  TxnInsurance  ChgTotal
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 csc       V123456789  PAY       CASUCL     2/8/2019    2/8/2019    CHECK         -181.22          1            SP    3386.6
 csc       V123456789  PAY       CASUCL     2/9/2019    2/9/2019    CHECK         -175.48          1            SP     0
 csc       V123456789  PAY       CASUCL     2/8/2019    2/8/2019    CHECK         -68.06           1            SP     0
```

[image: tiny image]

[tiny image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVvCX.png)

Comment: Did you want the result in SQL SERVER or just on SSRS? You can use the row_number() function as the answer suggests to return the result if 1 else 0.. in SSRS you can do similar with a iff statement.. something like = iif(RowNumber("yourgroupname") =1,Fields!ChgTotal.value,0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the inner query I have added a Row_Number function on the column AcctNumber.
This function will return a row number group by AcctNumber. So you will be start from 1 for every AcctNumber. In the outer query I have added a Case When to get the ChgTotal based on ROw Number.

```
SELECT 
    AcctNumber, VisitID, TxnType, TxnJournal, TxnSvcDate, TxnBchDate,  
    TxnNonChgCode, TxnAmount, TxnCount, TxnInsurance,  ChgTotal, 
    CASE 
       WHEN RowNumber = 1 THEN ChgTotal ELSE 0 
    END 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNumber ORDER BY AcctNumber) RowNumber,
         AcctNumber, VisitID, TxnType, TxnJournal, TxnSvcDate, TxnBchDate,  
         TxnNonChgCode, TxnAmount, TxnCount, TxnInsurance, ChgTotal
     FROM 
         YOUR_TABLE_NAME) AS A
```

Comment: Please don't just dump a pile of code - you need to **explain** in plain English what this code does, and how this solves the OP's question / problem.